# Rails migration: string to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I have in my DB a "tags" field, which is a string. But when many tags are stored, Rails returns an array because of "serialize :tags, Array" in the Project model.

How can I migrate my field to an array type, without having errors on the existing datas ?

Comment: `['tag1','tag2'].join(',')` => `'tag1,tag2'`

Comment: Nope, I want to transform the type in the DB because the way it's done, I can't search inside the array via an sql request.

Comment: create a new migration, which will store the column data, then drop it, and recreate the column with other type, then fill it with the data